# Python: Get the smallest item from a list inside a list

Tags: python

Let's say I have a list named data.

```
data = [[3.59, ['foo']], [2.34, ['bar', 'foo']]]
```

Now I want to find the index from the list in data, wich number in the list inside data at index 0 is the smallest. So that would be in my example 0 or 1 but because 2.34 is less then 3.59 it would return 1

Edit:

This is what i come up with but I don't think it is really efficient atm.

```
data = [[3.59, ['foo']], [2.34, ['bar', 'foo']]]
smallest_num_list = []

for list in data:
    for i in list[:1]:
        smallest_num_list.append(i)

for list in data:
    for i in list[:1]:
        if i == min(smallest_num_list):
            result = data.index(list)

print result
```

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried? We won't write the code for you.

Comment: @utdemir Yes of course I will edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
idx_min, val_min = min(enumerate(data), key=lambda i, x: x[0])
```

Comment: Will it work if there's several items with the same minimal value?

Comment: @hyst329, it'll return the first one.

Comment: @hyst329 This will work as `min()` function usually works, this means this will return the fist minimal value encountered.

Comment: @Sorry, i've meant something other. Will it work if we need _all_ such elements?

Comment: @hyst329 It will not work because `min()` return just one value. If you are looking for all the minimal values, you will have to first sort the list and then get group values at the beginning, as stated in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3538118/2291710).

Answer (score -2):

This will work and return a list of such minimal indices (if more than 1)

```
[i for i, e in enumerate(list) if e[0] ==  min([d[0] for d in list])]
```

Comment: This has `O(n**2)` complexity, this is pretty bad since the problem can be easily solved in linear time.

Comment: @utdemir you can compute minimum value only once, so no quadratic complexity

Comment: @hyst329: you *can*, but your code doesn't.  Lift finding the minimum out of your listcomp.

Comment: @hyst329, you aren't in your answer. Even then, it passes twice on the data, this can be done in just one pass.